# Tracking user activity when internet is offline, using javascript and perform them when internet is back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, offline-caching

What I am going to develop is an offline web application framework, where we can track all the http requests occurred when internet is down(e.g form submissions, ajax requests ect.) I know I can store static html pages, css/js script files, images etc. using the appcache. But I need to track user activities when internet is offline and sync them when it is online (like in gmail offline). I expect to do this using javascript. Is there a specific way to achieve this.

Comment: You could create an array which does store all the actions which the user does and check every 5 min if there is a connection and then send the array to your server back

Comment: @ciaodarwin Actually what I need is a way of detecting those actions. For e.g. when user submits a form when offline, I need a way to store the request along with all the headers, parameters etc.